# React Router how to change url without trigger re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, history, browser-history

I'm using react-router for React navigation, so are there any way to update url (in browser) without trigger re-render that switch to other route match with new url.

For example: I'm in the page of url "/books", then I just want browser url silently update to "/categories" without re-render the body content (so in this case, the body is still the content of books).

I found we can do it by using window.history.pushState but I'm not sure it's the best practice, I guess we can do it from API of react-router package.

I appreciate any helps, thanks in advance.